# app doesn't update and traitCollectionDidChange doesn't fire when user changes appearance in settings

Tags: ios, swift, ios-darkmode, uitraitcollection

In my app I allow the user to override the appearance that is set on the device.  Here's the class that handles updating the UI if they want to override the system-wide appearance:

```
class UserInterfaceStyleController {

init() {
    self.handleUserInterfaceStyleChange()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.handleUserInterfaceStyleChange), name: Notification.Name(OMGNotification.changeBizzaroMode.rawValue), object: nil)
}

@objc func handleUserInterfaceStyleChange() {
    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        let windows = UIApplication.shared.windows
        for window in windows {
            if UIScreen.main.traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle == .light {
                if UserDefaults.standard.bizzaroMode {
                    window.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .dark
                } else {
                    window.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light
                }
            }
            if UIScreen.main.traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle == .dark {
                if UserDefaults.standard.bizzaroMode {
                    window.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light
                } else {
                    window.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .dark
                }
            }
            window.subviews.forEach({ view in
                view.layoutIfNeeded()
            })
        }
    }
}
```

This works - the user flips the switch and the app changes the userInterfaceStyle. The problem is the app doesn't change appearance automatically when the user changes the system-wide appearance (set light or dark mode in settings), ONLY when they set it manually.

So I'm assuming I need to do some work when the user changes it system-wide, and traitCollectionDidChange seems to be what I need to use. Problem is it doesn't fire when the user changes the appearance in settings, ONLY when it's manually set in my app. 
I've got this code in a viewController to test that:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    // Lots of stuff

    override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
        print("We have a style mode change")
    }

    // Lots more stuff
}
```

When I manually override, it prints, "We have a style mode change".  When I go into settings and switch the system-wide appearance traitCollectionDidChange doesn't fire.

I swear I had this working fine at one point, but I've been trying to fix some weird issues for a while now when I use overrideUserInterfaceStyle and have burned through a lot of code changes.

I think I'm missing something obvious.  Before I started allowing the user to override, the app switched automatically in the background when the appearance was changed system-wide with no code at all. Now it doesn't and traitCollectionDidChange doesn't fire. What am I missing or doing wrong? Happy to provide more code if it could help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that you override the user interface style, which causes any system changes not to become propagated to your window. You need to set `overrideUserInterfaceStyle` to `.unspecified`, otherwise the system won't call the `traitCollectionDidChange` methods in your view stack on change.

In our apps, we offer the user three options: automatic, light and dark, where each option just sets `overrideUserInterfaceStyle` to the appropriate option.

By the way, you don't need to call `layoutIfNeeded()` on all your subviews—setting `overrideUserInterfaceStyle` triggers a redraw automatically.

Comment: Most of my views automatically redraw, but for some reason I have some that don't and I have to manually do it. I haven't quite figured out what causes it, it might have something to do with not being onscreen plus something else I haven't quite determined.