# traitCollectionDidChange not called on scheduled appearance (dark mode / light mode) change (e.g. at sunset / sunrise, or custom schedule)

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, darkmode, uitraitcollection

I have a navigation app. During a navigation session, I prevent the screen from sleeping. When users are driving/navigating around sunrise or sunset, appearance should change between light and dark mode.

In order to do this, I created a subclass of UIWindow:

```
class WindowWithDarkModeMonitor: UIWindow {

    override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
        super.traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection)
        print("traitCollectionDidChange")
    }

}
```

`traitCollectionDidChange` is supposed to be called whenever traits (like portrait/landscape and dark/light mode change). ([Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitraitenvironment/1623516-traitcollectiondidchange) (b.t.w. I know this method will be deprecated, but my app needs to support iOS16 for the moment, so I still need it).

Now, the problem is, `traitCollectionDidChange` is not called on a scheduled appearance change. It IS called when I switch between dark and light mode through the control center. It's also called when I rotate my device.

I browsed a LOT, and have tried a LOT, but can't find a solution. [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60532920/app-doesnt-update-and-traitcollectiondidchange-doesnt-fire-when-user-changes-a) comes close, but the top (and only) answer doesn't work for my case either.

After some testing, I actually found out that no app I know of changes from dark to light or vice versa when it's active in the foreground at the time of the scheduled change. You can try this yourself:

- Go to iOS Settings > Display & Brightness
- Set appearance to AUTOMATIC and for Options choose 'Custom Schedule' and choose the times so that a change is 1 or 2 minutes away.
- Now open Apple Mail, or Safari, or any other app that supports dark mode
- Make sure your display doesn't go to sleep, and wait until the minute passes where the dark/light switch should take place.
- Nothing happens!!!
- The dark/light switch is only applied after your iPhone is auto-locked or locked manually, and unlocked again.

I have a very strong feeling this is either an iOS bug (or a 'feature'?). In any case, it would be unfortunate for an app like mine, if I couldn't use the system's automatic dark/light switch at sunset/sunrise. I would have to build my own solution to determine if it's day or night (based on location and time zone). Not impossible, but I'd rather not re-invent the wheel, and keep my app as close to system behavior as possible.

So, is there any way to make the system call `traitCollectionDidChange` upon a scheduled appearance change (dark/light mode change)? Or, any other way to get notified about this?

Comment: You are correct that iOS does not honor the scheduled appearance change until the screen goes off and then on again. That's strange because macOS doesn't have this "feature". Many times I've been using my Mac as it switches to dark mode in the evening. Not sure why iOS handles this differently. But it means that there will be no way to make `traitCollectionDidChange` be called until the mode actually changes (after the screen goes off and on again).

Comment: Since no app will change appearance until the device is locked then unlocked, why does your app need to handle this differently than all other apps in this regard?

Comment: That’s a valid question. For a long time I indeed simply followed the default iOS behavior. Over time I received quite some user feedback on this though. People just expect it to change to dark mode when they are riding/driving around sunset time. Also my app is a motorcycle navigation app. With hands on the handlebars it’s not easy nor safe to lock/unlock your device while riding.

Comment: An added difficulty when riding motorcycle is that faceID doesn’t work with your helmet on, so to unlock your device you’d have to enter your passcode too. And that’s assuming you have touch enabled gloves. If you don’t then you’d have to find a place to stop and take of your gloves to lock and unlock your device.